# Smart way $2\times 2$ JNF

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

I wanted to find a fast way to construct the JNF (with basis transformation) of a $2\times 2$ Matrix which is not diagonalizable, which means that we need to have one eigenvalue with algebraic multiplicity 2 but geometric multiplicity being only 1.

My idea was to calculate calculate one eigenvector and construct the other basis vector somehow differently because we already know that the dimension of the nullspace of $(A- \lambda Id)^2$ is 2. So we know a lot, but is there any fast method now to evaluate the second basis vector with minimal effort?

Comment: If you know the eigenvalue $\lambda$, pick a $v \neq 0$ at random and compute $w = (A - \lambda I)v$. If you had bad luck and $w = 0$, pick a $v$ linearly independent from the first and start again. Then $v$ and $w$ give you a Jordan basis.

Comment: @DanielFischer Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Jordan normal form of an endomorphism $A$ of a $2$-dimensional vector space that is not diagonalisable, but has an an eigenvalue (for example if the scalar field is algebraically closed, that is always the case) is

$$\begin{pmatrix}\lambda & 1\\ 0 & \lambda\end{pmatrix}$$

(or the transpose of that), where $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue. So for a basis $B = (v_1,\, v_2)$ that achieves that normal form, we have

- $v_1$ is an eigenvector,
- $(A - \lambda I)v_2 = v_1$.

Conversely, every pair of nonzero vectors with these properties is a Jordan basis for $A$.

So a quick way to find a Jordan basis in this situation is to randomly choose a $w \neq 0$,and compute $v = (A - \lambda I)w$. If $v \neq 0$, then $(v,w)$ is a Jordan basis for $A$. If $v = 0$, then pick any $w'$ that is linearly independent from $w$. Since the eigenspace is one-dimensional, $w'$ is then not an eigenvector, hence $\bigl((A-\lambda I)w',\, w'\bigr)$ is a Jordan basis.